# Game + Web Server using ExpressJS

Tags: actionscript-3, node.js, sockets, express

I'm currently trying to develop a simple Flash game which talks to a node.js server.

My question is this: 
How might I go about making a server which differentiates web requests from game requests?

Here are the details of what I've done:

Previously, I used the `net` and `static` modules to handle requests from the game client and the browser, respectively.

TwoServers.js

```
// Web server
var file = new staticModule.Server('./public');
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    req.addListener('end', function(){
        file.serve(req, res, function(err, result){
                     // do something
        });
    });
}).listen(port1, "127.0.0.1");

// Game Server
var server = net.createServer(function(socket)
{
    // handle messages to/from Flash client
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.write('foo');
    socket.on('data', onMessageReceived);
});
server.listen(port2, "127.0.0.1");
```

I'd like to do the above with just an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) server listening in on a single port, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Here's what I'm thinking it might look like (doesn't actually work):

OneServer.js

```
var app = express();
app.configure(function()
{
    // ...
    app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  // The static server
});

app.get('/', function(req, res)    // This is incorrect (expects http requests)
{
    // Handle messages to/from Flash client
    var socket = req.connection;
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.write('foo');
    socket.on('data', onMessageReceived);
});
app.listen(app.get('port'));   // Listen in on a single port
```

But I'd like to be able to differentiate from web page requests and requests from the game.

*Note*: Actionscript's [XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html) makes TCP requests, so using app.get('/') is incorrect for two reasons:

1. When Flash writes to the socket, it isn't using the http protocol, so app.get('/') will not be fired when the game tries to connect.
2. Since I don't have access to correct the [net.Socket](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) object, I cannot expect to be reading or writing from/to the correct socket. Instead, I'll be reading/writing from/to the socket associated with the web page requests.

Any help on this would be much appreciated (especially if I'm reasoning about this the wrong way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a TCP connection is opened to a given port, the server (Node + Express) has no way of telling who made that connection (whether it's a browser or your custom client).

Therefore, your custom client **must** speak HTTP if it wishes to communicate with the Express server sitting on port 80.  Otherwise, the data you send over a freshly opened socket (in your custom protocol) will just look like garbage to Express, and it will close the connection.

However, this doesn't mean you can't get a TCP stream to speak a custom protocol over – you just have to speak HTTP *first* and ask to switch protocols.  HTTP provides a mechanism exactly to accomplish this (the `Upgrade` header), and in fact it is how WebSockets are implemented.

When your Flash client first opens a TCP connection to your server, it should send: (note line breaks MUST be sent as `CRLF` characters, aka `\r\n`)

```
GET /gamesocket HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: x-my-custom-protocol/1.0
Host: example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
​
```

The value of `Upgrade` is your choice, `Host` MUST be sent for all HTTP requests, and the `Cache-Control` header ensures no intermediate proxies service this request.  Notice the blank line, which indicates the request is complete.

The server responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: x-my-custom-protocol/1.0
Connection: Upgrade
​
```

Again, a blank line indicates the headers are complete, and after that final `CRLF`, you are now free to send any data you like in any format over the TCP connection.

To implement the server side of this:

```
app.get('/gamesocket', function(req, res) {
    if (req.get('Upgrade') == 'x-my-custom-protocol/1.0') {
         res.writeHead(101, { Upgrade: req.get('Upgrade'), Connection: 'Upgrade' });

         // `req.connection` is the raw net.Socket object
         req.connection.removeAllListeners(); // make sure Express doesn't listen to the data anymore... we've got it from here!

         // now you can do whatever with the socket
         req.connection.setEncoding('utf8');             
         req.connection.write('foo');
         req.connection.on('data', onMessageReceived);
    } else res.send(400); // bad request
});
```

Of course, remember that TCP is **not** a message-based protocol, it only provides a *stream*, and thus the `data` events of a `Socket` can either fragment a single logical message into multiple events or even include several logical messages in a single event.  Be prepared to manually buffer data.

Your other option here is to use [socket.io](http://socket.io), which implements a WebSockets server plus its own protocol on top of the WebSockets protocol.  The WebSockets protocol **is** message-based.  It mostly works just like I've outlined here, and then after HTTP negotiation adds a message framing layer on top of the TCP connection so that the application doesn't have to worry about the data stream.  (Using WebSockets also opens the possibility of connecting to your server from a HTML page if necessary.)

There is a [Flash socket.io client](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense. I may have to use the AS3 [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) class instead in order to customize the headers, if I were to go that route. Would using multiple ports with the express/http module along with the net module be considered bad practice, though?

Comment: It comes down to whether you're OK with some users being unable to use your game.  Many network environments (corporate networks, public WiFi, an end-user's paranoid firewall, etc) block outgoing connections to anything but port 80, so a user would be able to load your website and the swf, but then the game would be unable to connect back to your server on port *n*.  By doing a HTTP upgrade, you know that if a user can reach your website, the game will be able to connect as well.

Comment: Since I'm hosting on Heroku, it seems like I can't host on multiple ports anyway. So I think that you're right and that method might be the way to go.

Comment: Marked this as the solution. Going to go with the socket.io route, though it appears this library is a little bit dated (socket.io is on 0.9.x, FlashSocket.IO appears to support <= 0.7.x)